How to mock an object which is created at runtime in flutter?
I am testing a widget where I need to create an object of a database class. I want to mock a method from that class, how can I mock it? Let's suppose I have a function in that widget saveData():
void saveData(int number) async {
    // ...
    MyDatabase db = MyDatabase();
    bool success = await db.insert(number);
    // ...
}

So here, the saveData method will be called if I click a button from the widget. And I want to mock the insert method. How can we do that?
I didn't find any way to do this with mockito package.

Is your MyDatabase() a call to a factory constructor which returns a singleton or is it creating a new instace?

It's not possible for Mockito to do this for you.  You will need to add your own level indirection so that your testing code can replace the MyDatabase instance with a mock version.  For example:
void saveData(int number, {MyDatabase? db}) async {
    // ...
    db ??= MyDatabase();
    bool success = await db.insert(number);
    // ...
}

and then the testing code can do:
var db = MockMyDatabase();
when(db.insert(someNumber)).thenAnswer((_) async => true);
await saveData(someNumber, db: db);
verify(db.insert(someNumber).called(1);

